# Html password form assistance

Tags: html, forms

How would I create a form where if the user input is "password" and they click the continue button it would take them to another page?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use php for that so you'll have to change the extensions of your page to .php and host it on a wamp or mamp server

```
<?php

session_start();

$_POST['thenameyougavethepasswordfieldgoeshere'] = $password

if($password == "password"){
header("Location: thepage.php);
}else{
echo("Incorrect Password");
}

?>
```

Just add a type=Submit button to the html and there you go

Comment: Thanks for the help